# Load Openvpn Config on boot and mount network drive won't work on Debian

Tags: debian, mount, boot, openvpn, init.d

I have this script:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/vpnscript

### BEGIN INIT INFO

# Short-Description: Simple script to start a program at boot 
# Description:       A simple script from http://www.stuffaboutcode.comwhich    will start / stop a program a boot / shutdown.
### END INIT INFO

# If you want a command to always run, put it here

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" 
in start)
echo "Connecting to OPENVPN"
# Connect to the VPN
sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/connection1.ovpn
sudo mount -a
;;
stop)
echo "Stopping OPENVPN"
# Disconnect
killall openvpn
;;
*)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/vpnscript {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac
```

The Openvpn part works fine, but if it tries to use `sudo mount -a` the process starts doing nothing (or waiting for something, I don't know).

Is there an other way to do what I want to or is something wrong with my script? I am a starter at shell scripts.

Some notes:

- I tried using the Debian way of starting OpenVPN (`/etc/default/openvpn`) but this did not boot, so I've tried this way instead.
- The system's main `mount -a` happens before OpenVPN starts, and I've got an entry in `/etc/fstab` that refers to a network drive across the OpenVPN connection.
- The Server runs Openmediavault 3.0.

Comment: 1. If this is a boot script it's already running as root, so `sudo` is pointless. (If it's not a boot script, why is it in `/etc/init.d/`?) 2. Remove the space after `#!` on the first line 3. You've tagged this as Debian so why not use the Debian method for starting OpenVPN connections (see `/etc/default/openvpn`)? 4. What are you expecting to happen with `mount -a` that's not already triggered by the filesystem startup script? Please [edit your question to include this detail](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/340549/edit).

Comment: Edited the mainthread.

Comment: The two commands separately work perfect. But inside the Init.d they do not run.

Comment: No it doesnt. It does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem you're seeing is that OpenVPN stays running—so your `sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/connection1.ovpn` never returns. Your script thus never gets to the next line. (Also: init scripts run as root, so there shouldn't be a `sudo` there). So, trivially, you need to add an ampersand (`&`) to the end of that line or, better yet, give OpenVPN the `--daemon` option (but do read the OpenVPN docs about the limitations of that).

Of course, you *should* just use Debian's way of enabling a VPN: on Jessie, that'd be `systemctl enable openvpn@connection1.service`. Pre-jessie, or on Jessie without systemd, that'd be editing `/etc/default/openvpn` and changing the `AUTOSTART` line. (Probably you'll need to change the extension from `.ovpn` to `.conf` as well).

Then you'll find the next problem: OpenVPN will return *before* the VPN is up. But you can't start the mount until the VPN is actually passing traffic. The easiest way I found to fix this is a systemd service which pings the remote end of the VPN:

```
$ cat vpn-really-up.service
[Unit]
Description=Ping Einstein to make sure the VPN is really up
Wants=openvpn@vpn-name.service 
After=openvpn@vpn-name.service 

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/ping -c 2 -w 300 192.168.X.Y
TimeoutStartSec=330
```

Of course, you can use that ping line in an init.d script as well. (Note that this may not be the *best* way to do this—for example, maybe an `--route-up` command would be better—not sure if those didn't exist when I set this up, or if I didn't know about them. My machine is actually running testing.)

Then, you can create systemd mount units for your filesystem (note this one also depends on dnsmasq, because I use that to get some domains forwarded to a DNS server across the VPN, so that internal names work):

```
$ cat mnt-Einstein-music.mount 
[Unit]
Description=/mnt/Einstein/music
Requires=dnsmasq.service vpn-really-up.service
After=dnsmasq.service vpn-really-up.service remote-fs-pre.target

[Mount]
Where=/mnt/Einstein/music
What=Einstein.home:/srv/music
Options=nosuid,nodev,intr,rsize=4096,wsize=4096,nfsvers=3,fsc
Type=nfs
TimeoutSec=180s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(Mount on use would work too, and it's actually fairly easy with systemd—see `man 5 systemd.automount`).

Finally, your stop target needs fixing: you **must** unmount the filesystems before stopping the VPN. Otherwise, your machine will hang on reboot/shutdown. And you should test that it works—otherwise you'll ssh in to the machine one day and reboot it, and have to make an unplanned trip to hit the reset button.

PS: I also have this file:

```
$ cat openvpn@.service.d/local-after-ifup.conf 
[Unit]
Requires=networking.service
After=networking.service
```

... my guess is at one point that was required to make sure OpenVPN (and thus all the over-VPN filesystems) was stopped before systemd stopped the network interfaces.

Comment: Very nice. I've not got my head around `systemd` sufficiently for this so thank you from me (too)

Answer (score 0):

Short update.

OPENVPN works fine now, thanks.

Last thing i need to get work to, is this:

```
$ cat mnt-SHAREDNAS.mount 
[Unit]
Description=/mnt/SHAREDNAS
Requires=vpn-really-up.service
After=vpn-really-up.service remote-fs-pre.target

[Mount]
Where=/mnt/SHAREDNAS
What=//192.168.50.10/Users/RsyncNAS/SharedNASData
Options=uid=root,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm   0       0
Type=cifs
TimeoutSec=180s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But mount returns with
    error(22) : Invalid argument.

So my question is, what is the right way to turn this fstab line below to a correct .mount file:

```
//192.168.50.10/Users/RsyncNAS/SharedNASData  /media/SHAREDNAS  cifs   uid=root,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm   0       0
```